# How to load svg icon in my angular material application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angular-material

I am trying to add one icon to my angular material application . As per my understanding from documentation I have used `$mdIconProvider` like below:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $mdIconProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                '@': {
                    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html'
                }
            }
        });
    $mdIconProvider
        .iconSet('account', 'resources/icons/ic_account_circle_48px.svg', 48);
});
```

I have loaded this icon in my `$templateCache` using `ng-templates` grunt module.

And below is my template code:

```
<md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon md-menu-origin  md-svg-icon="account"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Icon is not getting display and getting below waring in my browser console.

[image]

Kindly guide me in right way as I am new to angular and angular material design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no icon named 'account' in material icons, check the list **[here](https://material.io/icons/)**

```
 <md-list-item class="md-3-line">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="ic_place_48px.svg"></md-icon>
              <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <h3>blueberries</h3>
                <p>content1</p>
                <p>content2</p>
              </div>
</md-list-item>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gsN4MPJ4mlHpXJpZlu6b?p=preview)**

Comment: This way I can load the image but I want to know how $mdIconProvider works how to register a icon which is in my icon folder using icon set and use that name to load l

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma check this sample https://plnkr.co/edit/lzpb1aid1pAndj0jnAZL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You need to give **md-svg-src** inside md-icon.

```
<md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button">                  
   <md-icon  md-menu-origin md-svg-src="resources/icons/ic_account_circle_48px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one svg icon file perhaps you can consider using it like this.

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="resources/icons/ic_account_circle_48px.svg" aria-label="Account"></md-icon>
```

Just a suggestion, if you start using font-icons instead of svg files, you may find it an easier way :)